# Create custom screen savers for a community of users, e.g. replaced daily via the Web

Tags: screen

For a community of people (e.g. of a certain faith, or with a shared interest or hobby) I want to enable the following capability. I want to give them a service they can sign up for, on a web site, that will download and replace their screen saver, e.g. on a daily basis.

Any suggestions on how this can be done? Limiting this initially to Windows (say XP + Vista) and to a single file for all users is good enough. Later on I may want to extend this to Mac and Linux and also be able to supply texts in multiple languages, customized per user.

I guess the easiest solution is simply to have a screen saver that presents a web page given to it as argument. Then I would make it point to www://mysite/dailypage and all I need to do is update this page.

One S/W I found that does this is [Web Screen Server](http://www.web-screen-saver.com). However it requires end user registration and payment ($19.95 - not cheap!). I would really prefer something that has a one time license and does not require end user registration (only a minimal installation and configuration) and ideally is free...

Feel free to reply by email.
Thanks,

-- Shaul (info@shauldar.com)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a fairly simple project to create a screensaver that contains an embedded web browser that called a specific URL, distributable to all the clients.

Indeed you would just need to update the page with the new content.

Do you need help with how to build this software?